# MacBook 2012 13" non touch bar not turning on after trying to replace SSD

Tags: macbook-pro, ssd

I bough a new SSD (2242 type) along with an adapter to replace my existing Apple SSD 128GB. I removed the back cover, disconnected the battery connector. inserted new SSD. But Mac did not recognized the new SSD.

Therefore, I decided to re-insert the old SSD. This time, when swap SSDs, I didn't disconnected the battery connector. But MAC was in shut down and swap was done quickly without any issue.

After that, when I'm trying to turn on the mac with old SSD in it, It doesn't turning on.

Can someone tell me what could be the issue?

Comment: Correction: MacBook Pro 2017. Not 2012.

Comment: Please edit your post and don't add information/correct yourself in the comments. Without any photos, more detailed description of what could have gone wrong and more info in general its basically impossible to tell from remote. I suggest you walk into a repair shop and tell them the situation. This will be much better than trying to solve this here IMO.

Comment: So, not recognizing the new SSD = poor connection probably. Then putting back the old one = poor or now damaged connection. Take it to a repair shop. They may be able to sort it, but you will likely make it worse.

Comment: @SolarMike thanks for the advice. I will go to a repair shop ASAP

Comment: When you say that the Mac doesn't turn on, I am taking it to mean that you see no visible signs of life. A faulty SSD or connector will still allow the system to come up to S0 power and boot a good deal of the way into EFI before hanging. You should confirm that you've got good power rails by taking the bottom cover off of the MacBook and observing that the green LEDs turn on when you try booting.

Comment: @pion is it ok to remove the back cover of the MacBook and turn it on? Are there any LED inside  MacBook Pro 2017 Non touch bar version?

Comment: @techmagister Yes to both.